# Pulling Json path from MySQL database using php

Tags: php, json, foreach, response, nested-loops

I am trying to pull JSON data path stored inside MySQL database but I am getting an error message when executing the PHP command.

```
$json = json_decode($response);
$json_feed = "data->value"; // i am pulling this data from my database
foreach ($json->$json_feed as $elem) { // getting an conversion error in this line
.....
}
```

Comment: Error? Please ALWAYS show us ALL the error message and never a summary

Comment: Variable access to object properties does not work across _multiple_ `->`. You would be accessing a property that is _literally_ named `data->value` with this.

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe says "Variable access to object properties does not work across multiple ->"

If your data is predictable enough to know you can split the string and use the bits you could do

```
// just setting up your data structure here
$json = new stdClass;
$sub = new stdClass;
$sub->value = [100, 200];
$json->data = $sub;


$json_feed = "data->value";
$bits = explode('->', $json_feed);
print_r($bits);

print_r($json->{$bits[0]}->{$bits[1]});
```

The result of that test code is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 200
)
```

So you can do

```
foreach ($json->{$bits[0]}->{$bits[1]} as $num){
    echo $num.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result would be

```
100
200
```

Comment: That's extremely helpful. Thank you for your prompt reply. Will give it a go soon. Best.

Comment: The problem remains, I still have to insert the sign (->) manually for each value in the foreach loop. Is there any way to built the full array structure automatically in the the foreach statement including the -> sign?

Comment: as described in my sample code. The error is a standard PHP stdClass conversion error Array to String